# Using Python to download images via urllib and testing if the website exists

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, urllib

I am writing a python script do download training images for a project I'm working on, and I'm writing a python script to download images from image-net. I'm below is what I'm running, but I keep getting this error:

```html
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

when it tries to go to: http://http://omusinternational.com/db3/00225/omusinternational.com/_uimages/oilRefinery.JPG.

I don't know how to fix it or tell it to throw that away and move on to the next item in my list. My code is as follows:

```html
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import httplib

neg_images_link = 'http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n03844673'
neg_image_urls = urllib.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()
pic_num = 1



for i in neg_image_urls.split('\n'):
    try:
        print(i)
        r = urllib.urlopen(i).getcode()
        print r
        if r == 200:
            urllib.urlretrieve(i, str(pic_num)+".jpg")
            img = cv2.imread(str(pic_num)+".jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            # should be larger than samples / pos pic (so we can place our image on it)
            if img != None:
                resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
                cv2.imwrite(str(pic_num)+".jpg",resized_image)
                pic_num += 1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Closing"
```

Comment: You get this error because of the typo: `http://http://`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is ok for you to skip all URLs with errors you can simply catch the IOError exception and continue with the next iteration of the main for loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import httplib

neg_images_link = 'http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n03844673'
neg_image_urls = urllib.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()
pic_num = 1


for i in neg_image_urls.split('\n'):
    try:
        print(i)

        try:
            r = urllib.urlopen(i).getcode()
        except IOError:
            print "error opening " + str(i)
            continue

        print r
        if r == 200:
            urllib.urlretrieve(i, str(pic_num)+".jpg")            
            img = cv2.imread(str(pic_num)+".jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            # should be larger than samples / pos pic (so we can place our image on it)
            if img != None:
                resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
                cv2.imwrite(str(pic_num)+".jpg",resized_image)
                pic_num += 1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Closing"
        break
```

Comment: So this is what i'm trying to impliment, but it isn't working right now:

Comment: the code I posted is working for me, could you say what is not working for you? Do you still get the same error message, an new one, other unexpected behaviour etc.